# What happens to a pointer after it has become a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I have a function that creates a unique pointer to a dynamically allocated object "c".

```
template<typename T, typename... TArgs> void addComponent(TArgs&&... MArgs) {

    if(!components.count(typeid(T))) {
        T* c = new T(std::forward<TArgs>(MArgs)...);
        c->entity = this;
        std::unique_ptr<Component> uPtr{ c };
        components[typeid(T)] = (std::move(uPtr));
        c->init();
    }

}
```

My understanding is that the unique_ptr takes control of the value of c because you can't have another pointer pointing too a unique_ptr, however c->init still works after c has been turned into a unique_ptr.

Why does this work? Does c somehow still point to the same new T() or is an entirely new object created?

Comment: Nothing happens to a pointer after it is used to initialise a `unique_ptr`.   The construction of `uPtr` results in `uPtr` containing (a representation of) a copy of the value `c`.    `uPtr` accepts responsibility for managing the lifetime of the dynamically allocated object pointed to by `c` (i.e. the object created by the `new` expression).   Assuming that elements of `components` are of type `unique_ptr<T>`, the assignment to `components[typeid(T)]` assigns that responsibility  (so, in this case, the use of `std::move()` achieves nothing). `c` still points to the same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping a raw pointer inside of a smart pointer does not change anything about the raw pointer.  It still points at the same memory it was originally pointing at.  The smart pointer is merely copying the pointer and then managing the pointed-at memory for you, `delete`'ing the memory when the smart pointer is destroyed or is otherwise assigned a different pointer.

FYI, it would be more safer and more efficient to use `std::make_unique()` instead of `new`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
void addComponent(TArgs&&... MArgs) {
    if (!components.count(typeid(T))) {
        auto c = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<TArgs>(MArgs)...);
        c->entity = this;
        c->init();
        components[typeid(T)] = std::move(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `unique_ptr` object stores a copy of the value of `c`. When the `unique_ptr` object is destroyed, its destructor will call `delete` on the stored pointer value.

The original variable `c` is not modified by the `unique_ptr`, and continues to point to the same object. It is perfectly fine to dereference it. The important thing is that since this pointer value will be deleted automatically by the `unique_ptr`, (1) you must not continue using its value after the `unique_ptr`'s lifetime expires, and (2) you must not try to delete it manually.

Answer (score 0):

No new objects are created and nothing takes control over anything. You wrapped the raw pointer with the smart pointer, and should not use the raw pointer anymore.

The smart pointers only work if you don't work around them by using the raw pointer. But the value of the variable `c` doesn't change because of the assignment operator in `std::unique_ptr` constructor. It remains the same, and you as the programmer should be disciplined about not using it directly any more.

Good practice would be to have it as a temporary variable that disappears after it's wrapped into a smart pointer; or instead of `new` just use `std::make_unique`.